# Excel Range by Code

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a particular problem I cannot seem to find an answer for in excel. I have a cell (E20)  which's value is: $G$7, I intent to modify cell (E20) in the future and use it as a filter.

When I want the value of cell (E20) to be used as a range the Formula, excel gives me an error and displays the problem:

```
=OFFSET($C$7,0,0,1,COUNTIF($D$8:"$G$7", ">0") +1
```

Mainly

```
COUNTIF($D$8:"$G$7" ...
```

How can I make this $G$7 value (which comes from E20) be a real cell reference, without the "" surrounding it?

Notes: I have already tried INDIRECT() and TEXT().

Comment: `How can I make this $G$7 be a cell reference?` - still can't understand this. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: Hopefully the edits make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a cell named X that has the value "$G$7"

You will also need append the "$D$8:" to this cell value inside INDIRECT() to reference the "dynamic" range:

```
=OFFSET($C$7,0,0,1,COUNTIF(INDIRECT("$D$8:" & X), ">0") + 1)
```

Also, using named ranges might help you keep track of this dynamic range.